# Adding a ComboBox to a DataGridView programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]

Suppose, I created this DataGridView in design view.

Now, I need to add items to the ComboBox column pro grammatically and show the item with index = 0.

The following code does load a ComboBox.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("1st Col", "2nd Col");
        Column3.Items.Add("AAAA");
        Column3.Items.Add("BBBB");
        Column3.Items.Add("CCCC");

    }
}
```

But, doesn't show 0-th item.

Comment: `0-th item` means `AAAA`? it doesn't display `AAAA` as selected or it doesn't have `AAAA` at all?

Comment: If you know what the default value is for newly added rows and you know the combo box values… could you not simply set its default value when you add the row?... `dataGridView1dgv.Rows.Add("1st Col", "2nd Col", "AAAA");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    cmb.Items.Add("AAAA");
    cmb.Items.Add("BBBB");
    cmb.Items.Add("CCCC");

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("1st Col", "2nd Col");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set current value for each cell in your column.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
    dataGridView[3, i].Value = "AAAA";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm proposing you an alternative way the set the default/initial value of a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, using a custom `CellTemplate`.

Assuming that (from the image shown), your ComboBox column is `Column[2]`, you could assign it this custom `CellTemplate`, which can be initialized with a default value:
(Here, the default value is of type `String`, but you could make it generic if needed)

```
public class ComboBoxCell : DataGridViewComboBoxCell
{
    private static string psDefaultValue;
    public ComboBoxCell()
        : base() { this.Value = psDefaultValue; }

    public void DefaultValue(string Value)
    {
        psDefaultValue = Value;
        this.Value = Value;
    }
    public override Type ValueType => typeof(String);
    public override object DefaultNewRowValue => psDefaultValue;
}
```

When initializing a `DataGridView`, assign the custom `CellTemplate` to the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`:

```
ComboBoxCell ComboBoxCellTemplate = new ComboBoxCell();
dataGridView1.Columns[2].CellTemplate = ComboBoxCellTemplate;
```

Then, after filling in the ComboBox items list, define the default value and assign it using the custom `DefaultValue()` method of the `CellTemplate`:

```
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1
                            .Columns[2])
                            .Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" });

((ComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Columns[2]
                            .CellTemplate)
                            .DefaultValue(((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1
                            .Columns[2]).Items[0].ToString());
```

After that, define the `DatagridView` DataSource. This way, for all new rows, the `DataGridVieewComboBoxColumn` will present the default value, the first item of the ComboBox in this case.